# Where I can find Rust functions to get values from non-uniform probability distributions?

Tags: rust, statistics, distribution

I'm aware of `rand::distributions`, but all I can find is **random** sampling.

I also want to display the distribution curve to the user, especially for those that depend on shape parameters like the Beta distribution, but I can't find a function to get an arbitrary value.

Essentially, I want to plot a graph of the distribution by doing something like

```
for x in 1..100 {
   let y = beta.sample(x as f64 / 100.0);
   // add x/y to graph
}
```

Where can I find the proper function to get these values? I've searched both the Rust rand book and the repository and can't figure it out.

Comment: You'll need a package, just search for distributions. An example is [`statrs::distribution`](https://docs.rs/statrs/0.10.0/statrs/distribution/index.html).

Comment: I searched but didn't find that one. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I assume you mean "non-uniform", not "non-random".